# Modifying offset of # link?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a fixed top bar - so if you click on an internal link (`<a href="#xxx">`) it gets obscured. Is there any way for me to force (via Jquery/JS) so that any #xxx link gets automatically offset Z pixels?

As requested, example link: http://examine.com/supplements/Creatine/#ref32

Comment: We need your relevant HTML and CSS before we can help you.  Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to handle this via html/css changes as opposed to using javascript to correct the issue. Place your content in a scrollable div with a margin at the page top as a placeholder for the fixed content. If you post your html then more specific advice can be given.

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/CsJ3Y/3/

```
body { overflow: hidden; }
#header { position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 50px; background: gray; border: 1px solid black; }
#content { 
    overflow: scroll; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid blue; 
}
```

html

```
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">
    <div>
        Page Content <br />
        <a id="a1" href="#anchor2" name="anchor1">Anchor 1</a>                
        <a id="a2" href="#anchor1" name="anchor2">Anchor 2</a>   
    </div>
</div>​
```

Comment: Added a link - need to modify JS behavior of <a href="#xx"> clicks.

Comment: @SolOrwell - anchors are not javascript. So you can't modify their behavior. You can scroll to a different location after navigation via javascript, but it is the wrong way to solve this problem. Solve it by fixing your html/css instead. My example is the way you should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Since I just had to deal with this...

HTML:

```
<h1><span class="offsetTarget" id="title">&#8203;</span>My Title</h1>

...

<a href="#title">This is a link</a>
```

CSS:

```
.offsetTarget { position: relative; bottom: 50px; }
```

50px can be whatever the height of your bar is.  You need *something* in the span, and the `&#8203;` (zero-width space) worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$('a[href^=#]').offset({ top: 10, left: 10 });
```

?

Comment: That modifies the display of <a href="#xx"> links. What I need is if you click on it, it takes you to the <a name="xx"> position, but offsets it by 20 pixels.